# Key misbehaving in Spanish layout in Linux under KDE

Tags: linux, keyboard-layout, kde

### Problem

If the Spanish layout is selected from the list of configured keyboard layouts, whenever I press the key which should correspond to `<` I get `\` (as if I was using the English layout); every other key works fine.

### Background

I am using a Durgod Taurus K310 keyboard with a ISO UK layout:
[image: Durgod Taurus K310 keyboard]

I have two layouts configured in my system: English (UK) and Spanish (Windows)

In a Spanish keyboard, the `<` and `>` symbols are placed in a key immediately to the right of the left Shift key. If I go to `KDE System Settings > Hardware > Input Devices > Keyboard > Layouts` and click "Preview" for the Spanish layout, I can see that the layout matches what I would expect, in particular that key in question:
[image: Preview]

For contrast, see the English (UK) layout:
[image]

Whenever I have my Spanish layout enabled, everything works fine with the exception of that key, which behaves as if I were using the English layout:

- <kbd><</kbd>: `\`
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd><</kbd>: `|`
- <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd><</kbd>: `¦`

### Debug information

When checking `setxkbmap -query` in this situation I get the following result:

```
$ setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     gb,es
variant:    ,winkeys
```

Funnily enough, if I run `setxkbmap es` on the terminal, the problem goes away. In that case, I get the following ouput:

```
$ setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     es
```

I have checked what happens in `xev` in each case when I press the key and these are the results:

#### After `setxbmap es` (works fine)

```
KeyPress event, serial 57, synthetic NO, window 0x5800001,
    root 0x1d4, subw 0x0, time 13307375, (587,288), root:(587,342),
    state 0x0, keycode 94 (keysym 0x3c, less), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (3c) "<"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (3c) "<"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 57, synthetic NO, window 0x5800001,
    root 0x1d4, subw 0x0, time 13307446, (587,288), root:(587,342),
    state 0x0, keycode 94 (keysym 0x3c, less), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (3c) "<"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

#### Without running `setxkbmap es` (buggy behaviour)

```
KeyPress event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x400001,
    root 0x1d4, subw 0x0, time 13889008, (1163,392), root:(1163,446),
    state 0x2000, keycode 94 (keysym 0x5c, backslash), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (5c) "\"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (5c) "\"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x400001,
    root 0x1d4, subw 0x0, time 13889087, (1163,392), root:(1163,446),
    state 0x2000, keycode 94 (keysym 0x5c, backslash), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (5c) "\"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Note how `state` is `0x2000` in this case and was `0x0` for the case in which it works correctly... Not sure what it means, though

### System information

For reference, I am using:

```
Operating System: Arch Linux
KDE Plasma Version: 5.21.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.82.0
Qt Version: 5.15.2
Kernel Version: 5.10.41-1-lts
OS Type: 64-bit
Graphics Platform: X11
```

**NOTE:** I am aware that I can use <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>z</kbd> and <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>x</kbd> to get the `<` and `>` symbols, but I'd like to fix it nonetheless.